# accessing a function's parameter in its child function

Tags: python, function

I am trying to use a function's parameter in its child function but getting an error that its not defined.

Sample example code is written below: for simplicity parent function is defined as parent and child as child.

```py
def child():
    i += 1
    print(i)

def parent(i):
    print(2*i)
    child()
```

P.S. I don't want to pass `i` as parameter in `child()` as it will not work in my original code.

I have searched and found some solution using classmethods but I want any other possible way.

Comment: Show how you are calling parent() please.

Comment: "I don't want to pass i as parameter in child() as it will not work in my original code" <- Then your example code is useless - it does not explain the real problem.

Comment: For the most part, the only way that I can possibly see this approach implemented is with the `global` keyword. Although, I don't believe that would be a *good* solution, it may be the only one.

Comment: @wuno just asking the user to input a number(i) and pass it to the function parent.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. Python is statically scoped; `child` will not look in the scope of a function from which it is *called*  for a variable definition, only scopes in which it is *defined*. What you want requires *dynamic* scoping. (Note: this is a different issue than static vs. dynamic *typing*, which involves the types of values you can assign to a name.)

Comment: While this is technically true there's probably some way to fix OP's design. The sample code does not give us enough information, however.

Comment: While I agree the question needs some clarification, I though the point about scoping was worth making.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is not possible in Pythonic way. @chepner has already describes the background of it in his answer.

You can make "work-around" with globals to see the input variable of parent function. I have written an example but it is totally not Pythonic and it is not recommended.

**Example:**

```
def child():
    global child_var
    child_var += 1
    print("Child: {}".format(child_var))

def parent(i):
    global child_var
    print("Parent: {}".format(2*i))
    child_var = i
    child()

child_var = None

parent(5)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
Parent: 10
Child: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with having classes and objects, then you might try this workaround..

```
class xyz:
    
    def child(self):
        self.i += 1
        print(self.i)
    
    def parent(self,i):
        self.i = i
        print(2*i)
        self.child()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xyzObject = xyz()
    xyzObject.parent(5)
```